# visual studio code or visual studio ide for web dev?

Tags: mysql, visual-studio, ide

I have discovered that mysql has an extension that is for visual studio, but it is for ide one.

Before, I used visual studio code for this.  Should I move to the ide?

I am thinking of moving, but I don't know if it is for web developing or only window linux apps etc.

I want to do it because the mysql integration is on it.

Comment: I use both depending on what I'm doing, Visual Studio Code is much faster than the IDE so I prefer to use that

Comment: So maybe I should download the client versions of MySQL and use vs code ?

Comment: Visual Studio Code is not an IDE, it's an enhanced editor. It really depends on the type of application you are trying to build. If you are using ASP.NET stack I would strongly recommend Visual Studio.

Comment: @mberacochea if you are going to bother suggesting a question edit, please do a FULL edit to include improvements to English/grammar/capitalization.  This minimizes the number of total edits required to clean up the question.